# Collision detection inconsistent

Tags: swift, xcode, collision-detection, physics

My collision detection is working most of the time, but sometimes one physics body will go inside the other, when they should collide. I have a car with physics and road sides with physics. The car will blow through the road sides occasionally. I'm moving the car forward by position, however I have also tried moving forward by force and the same thing happens. Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this?

I've defined my physics categorys like so;

```
struct PhysicsCategory: OptionSet {
let rawValue: UInt32
init(rawValue: UInt32) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

static let CarCategory =            PhysicsCategory(rawValue: 0b00001)
static let RoadSidesCategory =      PhysicsCategory(rawValue: 0b00010)
static let NoCollisionsCategory =   PhysicsCategory(rawValue: 0b00000)
}
```

Giving the car physics like so;

```
func giveCarPhysics(physics: Bool) {
    //give physicsBody to the car and set to collide with the background
    if physics {
        self.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:  CGSize (width: self.size.width * 0.6, height: self.size.height * 0.9), center: CGPoint(x: self.anchorPoint.x, y: self.anchorPoint.y + self.size.height / 2))
        self.physicsBody?.mass = vehicleMass
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody?.friction = 0.5
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = airResistance
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.RoadSidesCategory.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.RoadSidesCategory.rawValue 
    }
}
```

And then giving the road sides physics;

```
func createPhysicsRight() {
        for (index, backgroundImageRight) in self.physicsRight.enumerated() {

            let roadSpriteR = SKSpriteNode()
            roadSpriteR.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            roadSpriteR.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(self.physicsCounterR) * self.frame.size.height)
            roadSpriteR.zPosition = 0
            roadSpriteR.name = "RoadR \(index)"

            print(roadSpriteR.name as Any)

            roadSpriteR.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: backgroundImageRight)
            roadSpriteR.physicsBody?.mass = backgroundMass
            roadSpriteR.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            roadSpriteR.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            roadSpriteR.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.RoadSidesCategory.rawValue
            roadSpriteR.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
            roadSpriteR.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
            roadSpriteRArray.append(roadSpriteR)
    }  
}

func createPhysicsLeft() {
    for (index, backgroundImageLeft) in self.physicsLeft.enumerated() {

        let roadSpriteL = SKSpriteNode()
        roadSpriteL.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        roadSpriteL.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(self.physicsCounterL) * self.frame.size.height)
        roadSpriteL.zPosition = 0
        roadSpriteL.name = "RoadL \(index)"
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: backgroundImageLeft)
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody?.mass = backgroundMass
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.RoadSidesCategory.rawValue
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CarCategory.rawValue
        roadSpriteL.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CarCategory.rawValue 
        roadSpriteLArray.append(roadSpriteL)
    }
 }
```